# MS Excel show hidden columns that are scrollable

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a Gantt chart spreadsheet that has a scrollable section that shows the chart.
As you can see from the image, part of the chart is hidden and one has to scroll to see the rest of it. How can I scale all the columns and rows that contain the chart so that I can have it fit on one page such that I can screenshot the chart as a whole or print it on one page?

I've attempted setting the Width and Height under Page Layout to 1 page but this doesn't work.
I've also tried to minimize the cell sizes F - BI but this just shrinks the section the chart is displayed. Using MS Excel 2016.

[image: Gantt Chart Screenshot Image Here]

Comment: Try using Excel, View, Freeze Panes.

Answer (score 0):

Select the **whole Worksheet** and go to **View**- **Window** group and select **Unfreeze Panes**:

[image]